# Socket.io Server Emit only works after server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

Please forgive me if this comes out to be a a real stupid question.
I was watching a tutorial on Socket.io and everything worked great. So I wanted to try it in a reactjs app. **But the problem is that while I am able to emit from client side, I'm not able to do it from server side.**
**The emit works if I restart the server** and what I mean by that is that when I run the application, initially server logs the message and after the restart, the client logs the message.

**client side**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import socket from '../socketConfig'

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        socket.on('hello',(data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        })
        socket.emit('call','this is from client');
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

**socketConfig**

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:4000/");

export default socket;
```

**Server side**

```
var express = require('express');

var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('listening for requests on port 4000,');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('hello','msg from server');
  socket.on('call', (data)=>{console.log(data)});
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem code sending from the server?  Are you saying that `socket.emit('hello','msg from server');` only worked the very first time and doesn't work on subsequent new connections?  Or is there some other server code that's trying to emit that isn't working?

Comment: console on server side logged the message "this is from client" due to socket.emit('call','this is from client) but there was no message on browsers console which I was expecting from socket.emit('hello','msg from server'); . But when I restarted the server I got the message on browser console.

Comment: I don't know much about React, but I wonder if you don't have your listener for the `hello` message installed soon enough after connecting so maybe the client misses that first message.  When you reboot the server, the socket.io client sees that it lost the connection and reestablishes it.  By then, then listener is appropriately in place.

Comment: It kind of makes sense to me. But I don't know how to check it.

Comment: You can test the theory by putting a delay on the server sending like this: `setTimeout(() => {socket.emit('hello','msg from server');}, 2000);`.  If that makes the message show up, then you will have to better coordinate the timing between connecting and installing listeners on the client.

Comment: I tried it but the problem still persists. I believe it has something to do with react because the server side code was same and working when I did it without react.  I just don't know what. Still thanks for your help.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried your theory with 5 second delay and it worked. I am new to socket.io Can you please a little bit more about this, why this behaviour happened ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be in the url you are using - socket.io can be finicky since it isn't strictly a web socket, it's a wrapper around long polling and websockets. So you may have to specify which transport to use, since the socket handling is done on the same port as the http handling.

Try this url from the client side:

`ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But now I believe that the problem was in client side code itself. But I still don't understand why restarting the server behaved in the way I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was listening to events in copmponentDidMount() but using componentDidUpdate() solved the problem.

**App Component**

```
    state = {
        socket:null
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            socket:io("http://localhost')
        })  

    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        let sokt = this.state.socket;
        sokt.on('connect',()=>{
            sokt.on('hello',(data)=>console.log(data)); //logged: msg from server
            sokt.emit('call',"This is from client"); //logged: This is from client
        })
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct way to do this

Comment: I am also facing the same problem but your solution doesn't work for me. Any thoughts ?? Also, I am using functional components. But implement the same with class component also, didn't work.